# Many to many query in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have 4 tables:

> Address - AddressID, City, Address, ZipCode
>
> OBAddress - OBID, AddressID
>
> OB -  OBID
>
> States - StateID, StateAbbreviation

How do I join the three tables which are in a many to many relationship?  I tried:

```
var recordsPhysicalAddress = ( from a in db.Addresses
    join oba in db.obAddresses on a.AddressID equals oba.AddressID
    join ob in db.obAddresses on oba.obID equals passedinID
    join s in db.States on a.StateID equals s.StateID
    where oba.obID == ob.obID
    && a.AddressTypeID == '5' //5 is records physical address
    select new
    {
        a.Address1, 
        a.City, 
        a.StateID,
        s.StateAbbreviation,
        a.ZipCode
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I don't think you need that "where oba.obID == ob.obID" since you're already doing a join on that.

Comment: And, come to think of it, why are you doing the joins and not using anything from the join at all? Why even bother joining them?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = (from a in db.Addresses
             join oba in db.obAddresses on a.AddressID equals oba.AddressID
             // do not join with db.obAddresses again
             join s in db.States on a.StateID equals s.StateID
             where oba.obID == passedinID // filter here
                   && a.AddressTypeID == '5'
             select new {
                   a.Address,
                   a.City,
                   a.StateID,
                   s.StateAbbreviation,
                   a.ZipCode
             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I put some remarks in comments to query. But still wonder why you have mentioned forth table in question?

Comment: @user1220099 are you sure there is some data, that matches your query conditions? Btw addresstypeID is of type char?

Comment: damn, that was it the whole time, addresTypeID is not char, it's of type int.  Stupid mistake, thanks for catching that.....